# Inserting unique elements into vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pair of  vector of integers and double. For example my vector is the following (The first vector of the pair is small, atmost of size 10 elements):

```
 vector<pair<vector<int>, double> >  vecIntDouble;
 vector<int> vecInt1; //always small atmost of size 10 elements
 vecInt1.push_back(0); vecInt1.push_back(1); vecInt1.push_back(3);
 vecIntDouble.push_back(make_pair(vecInt1,0.4));
 vector<int> vecInt2; //always small atmost of size 10 elements
 vecInt2.push_back(0); vecInt2.push_back(2); vecInt2.push_back(3);
 vecIntDouble.push_back(make_pair(vecInt2,0.3));
```

Now I want to enforce the following conditions on this vector

1. When I pull elements from this vector, I want to retrieve the elements in ascending order based on the second value of the pair. i.e, I want vecIntDouble to be sorted as: ((0,1,3),0.3),((0,2,3),0.4)
2. I want the vector of ints to be inserted in the vector uniquely. i.e if I have another entry which needs to be inserted into vecIntDouble as ((0,2,3),0.4) then during retrieval, I this entry should not be inserted into the vector.

I understand I can use priority queue for the same. I implemented the same. However, my code was extremely slow because of the constant look-ups being done to find vector uniquely. Therefore, I am looking for a faster implementation. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Additionally, elements are at random getting inserted and popped from this vector. i.e. if I pull ((0,1,3),0.3), then I dont want this element to be popped at the next retrieval (((0,1,3),0.3),((0,2,3),0.4)).

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at `std::map`.

Comment: @templatetypedef I need to do 1 million insertions and pops(), so std::map is not a good choice for the same

Comment: Are you sure about that? Map insertions and deletions only require O(log n) comparisons each. Storing things in a vector will take way more than that.

Comment: to speed up `vecInt`s lookups you may use a hash function, and effectively replace `std::map` suggested above with `std::unordered_map`, where lookups are of amortized O(1) complexity

Comment: if you can completely predict what vecInts are on your dataset, then you could use a perfect hash function which is guaranteed to produce hash values with no collisions.